# iScroll in backbone returns object to a start position

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, iscroll

Ok , I wrote a this code , and it gets the elements and do stuff on them for iScroll but its not working as it should , when I move the block with the mouse it always returns to a start position , what I'm missing ?

```
initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Products();
        this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('sync', this.init, this);

        this.collection.fetch();

        var myScroll,myScroll2,myScroll3;
        function loaded() {

        myScroll = new iScroll('products_container');   
        myScroll2 = new iScroll('competitors_container');
        myScroll3 = new iScroll('features_container');
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);

        window.addEventListener('load', setTimeout(function () { loaded(); }, 200), false);
    },
```

Comment: check your container height at called function 'loaded'